# How to Make Angular Material Tabs as Wizard with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

> I would like to Make `<md-tab>`s as Wizard by adding Next Button.
>
> i added My code and created a Plunker with next Buttons Could guys take a look please add your code to make it wizard

Plunker Added :-
http://plnkr.co/edit/p9mMyaqqHWtVyAEeisd1?p=preview

```
 <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
           <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Next</md-button>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <p>Lorem  risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
          
          <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Next</md-button>
        </md-content>
         
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="three">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
           <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Finish</md-button>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
```

Comment: This is not a real question. Modify your post to clear about what you're asking exactly.

Comment: Mr.Miszy  I dont Know what you are expecting as Title . I gave all the information Needed at the same time with Plunker. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have add an attribute to your  **md-tabs** tag **md-selected** attribute to set the selected tab index .. 
so first you have to add  ng-controller

```
<md-content class="md-padding" ng-controller="tabCtrl">
```

after bind you have bind the value of selectedIndex

```
 <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="selectedIndex">
```

after you have to add ng-click  to your button to call nextTab()

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="nextTab()">Next</md-button>
```

end of it  ...  here is the controller  you need

```
// Code goes here
var moduler = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);
moduler.controller("tabCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.max = 2;
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
  $scope.nextTab = function() {
    var index = ($scope.selectedIndex == $scope.max) ? 0 : $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;

  };

}]);
```

i hope this example helps you...

here is the  example at plunker as you wish

http://plnkr.co/edit/iNEXWXUBDvsrKgUSelkW?p=preview

Comment: Could you Please add it to My Plunker

Answer (score 0):

> you could use the Wizard also which serves your cause

github Link :-
https://github.com/Matesign/material-wizard

sample code follows

```
<mt-wizard btn-progress-color="#D8D8D8"  btn-bg-color="#FAFAFA" active-btn-bg-color="#E9E9E9" chevrons-always-visible="true" on-finish="submit()">
    <mt-wz-step title="Step 1" step-img="step1.svg" on-exit="onExitStep1()">
     </mt-wz-step>
</mt-wizard>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rp5qJykW2DD1A7EvaVZP?p=preview

Comment: Hi Developer2015. I tried your version of the wizard. checked the plunker and saw some issues with some inputs showing as textboxes and not applying the usual angular material styling. the same applies to my code and was wondering if you have a fix for it.